# Visual Studio Code not understanding CMake -DDEBUG

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

Developing on Ubuntu 18.04 with CMake 3.15.3 and Visual Studio Code 1.39.2. My C++ project has a CMakeLists.txt with this line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DDEBUG")
```

In the C++ code, the `DEBUG` define can be checked like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    DebugFunction();
#else
    ReleaseFunction();
#endif
```

This all works as expected. Comment out the `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG...` line and `ReleaseFunction` is called. Uncomment and `DebugFunction` is called.

The problem is that the Visual Studio Code editor does not understand whether the `DEBUG` symbol is actually defined. Code always assumes ``DEBUG is not defined and greys out `DebugFunction`.

Is there a simple way to get Visual Studio Code to understand which symbols are defined and which are not? Presumably this requires getting Code to look inside `CMakeLists.txt`...but how?

Answer (score 1):

For windows, may be you could try
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /DEBUG")
or
add_definitions("-DDEBUG")

Comment: Will try, though I'm developing on Linux. Problem is not that the symbol is not visible to `gcc` (it is), but that it is invisible to `Code`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get VS Code to recognize anything I added to CMake, but after some research I switched to using NDEBUG. This is part of the C standard, set automatically by CMake, and recognized by Intellicode in VS Code so that it is greyed out or not appropriately with no changes in CMakeLists.txt files.

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
  ReleaseFunc();
#else
  DebugFunc();
#endif
```